# How can I modify packets read from pcap file using Pyshark and save it in new pcap file?

Tags: scapy, pcap, tcpdump, tshark, pyshark

I am trying to read packets from `input.pcapng` file and modified the packets as shown below. I want to save the list of these packets in new pcap file. Please let me know on how to proceed.

```
import pyshark
from scapy.utils import wrpcap

# open the input capture file
input_capture = pyshark.FileCapture('input.pcapng',keep_packets=True)

packets = []
# iterate through each packet in the input capture file

for packet in input_capture:
    #some modification
    if len(packet.layers) > 7:
        count = 0
        packet.layers.pop(0)
        for i,layer in enumerate(packet.layers):
            count += 1
            if layer.layer_name == 'eth':
                break
        packet.layers = packet.layers[count-1:]
    packets.append(packet)



wrpcap('output.pcap', packets)


input_capture.close()
```

(Note: I tried wrpcap , Pcapwriter but couldn't succeed.)

Answer (score 0):

input_capture = pyshark.FileCapture('input.pcapng',output_file=filepath ,keep_packets=True)

output_file can save the captured Packets

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?